# How to loop inside of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to loop data inside of array, without loop array, anyone can help me with this problem?
this is my code..

```
<?php
$arrUtil = array();
while($dtRoomsUtil = mfa($roomsUtil)){
    $arrUtil[] = array(
        "id" => $dtRoomsUtil['id'],
        "name" => $dtRoomsUtil['name'],
        "label" => $dtRoomsUtil['label'],
        "type" => $dtRoomsUtil['type']
    );
}
while($dtUtils = mysql_fetch_array($quUtils)){
$arrData = array(
 foreach($arrUtil as $value){
  $value['name'] => $dtUtils[$value['name']]
 }
}
);
?>
```

thats give me error, and i think because a foreach function, anybody know about the other ways to solve this problem?

Thanks for help..

Comment: attach your array `$arrUtil` with your post.

Comment: More explanation of what you are trying to achieve please. Show us an example of the arrays you are processing

Comment: Would be nice to see the error too...

Comment: sorry, i already edit the code.. i looping my query name is **dtUtils**, and got a 3 loop, but i want to looping array with name **arrUtil** inside **arrData** ..

Answer (score 1):

You can't init array in such way. Make it like so:

```
$arrData = array();
 foreach($arrUtil as $value) {
  $arrData[$value['name']] = $dtUtils[$value['name']];
 }
```

Comment: please first make sure what OP want? Your approach is correct but if you did this like so fast with out asking OP what he/she want then they never make a complete question.

Comment: maybe, you're right. But i have no doubts that OP wants to init an array by a  loop. It seems the question in current state gives the information enough

Answer (score 1):

you can **push** your data into array,
use `array_push($array,$element)` in the loop